# Asp.Net sharing session across multiple web applications?

Tags: asp.net, iis, session, session-state, asp.net-4.0

I have to share session data between two different Asp.Net Application. The deployment of web apps are as shown below.

```
 WebSite
    --WebApp1
    --WebApp2
```

I have to use same Session data between **WebApp1** and **WebApp2**. Also WebApp1 and WebApp2 both share the same **Domain**(www.WebSite.com) and **AppPool**

What is the easiest way to make these two WebSite share the Session State data?

> Can I use Asp.Net State Server to
>   share the Session data between the above two WebApps?

Comment: What would you use as a server, because you need to use some sort of database I believe?

Comment: @Brian:State Server can be used to save session without using Sql Server.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Synchronizing ASP.NET Sessions Across Multiple Sites](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/391912/synchronizing-asp-net-sessions-across-multiple-sites)

Answer (score 1):

you can use stateserver which stores the session state in memory, for more details [go here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972429.aspx)

Comment: That explain how to use Session State Server. Not how to share the Session state between two WebApps.

Comment: I don't believe that StateServer will allow you to share session information easily between two applications, as the session key is application specific (it is good for sharing state between the same application running on multiple servers). What @Amitabh will need to do is save the information into a shared database (or similar) and work from there. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/391912/synchronizing-asp-net-sessions-across-multiple-sites and others under "Related" to the right -->